# An integral over n-dimensional unit cube

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration

I'm trying to calculate the following $\text{n}$-dimensional integral:

$$ \int_{[0, 1]^n}  (1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2}) ^ {- {{n+3}\over{2}}}  \ \mathrm dx_{1}\mathrm dx_2 ... dx_n  $$

where ${[0, 1]^n}$ is a $\text{n}$-dimensional unit cubic.

Is there a closed-form for this integral?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a closed form for $$\int_{[0, 1]^n}  (1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2}) ^ {- {{n+1}\over{2}}}  \ \mathrm dx_{1}\mathrm dx_2 ... dx_n$$ - https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-do-I-solve-this-triple-integral-displaystyle-iiint_-0-1-3-frac-1-1-x-2-y-2-z-2-2-dx-dy-dz

Comment: @Svyatoslav I couldn't find the closed form there.

Comment: Could you reach the solution via the attached link? In fact this is another integral (as I wrote - with the power $-\frac{n+1}{2}$, not $-\frac{n+3}{2}$ of the desired integral). The specific symmetry helped to get this closed form, and I'm not sure that the closed form can be obtained for the desired integral as well (at least, for the arbitrary $n$)

Comment: @Svyatoslav Sorry, couldn't find it, there were various integrals, none with a general $n$ power. Why don't  you just post it as an answer?

Comment: @user619894 You can find the closed-form from this page 
 [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/319058/integrating-over-a-hypercube-not-a-hypersphere)

Comment: excellent! in fact https://mathoverflow.net/a/319068 is the method I proposed. We should mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry, probably, this is specificity of Quora. The link leads me directly to the solution, but probably because I'm a subscriber. Very strange, in fact. But there are already other solutions available at mathoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

This is solution for another integral ($\int_{[0, 1]^n}  (1+ \sum_{k=1}^{n} x_k^{2}) ^ {- {{n+1}\over{2}}}  \ \mathrm dx_{1}\mathrm dx_2 ... dx_n$), but it might be of interest as well.

We denote $\displaystyle I(n)=\int_{[0,1]^{n-1}}\frac{1}{(1+{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+…+{x_{n-1}}^2)^{n/2}}dx_1…dx_{n-1}\tag*{}$

Let’s consider the space of $n$ dimensions; radius-vector $\vec R=x_1 \vec {e_1}+…+x_n \vec {e_n}$ ,

and $R=\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+…+{x_{n}}^2}$ - its norm.
We also denote $\vec \eta=\frac{\vec R}{R}$, and the field $\vec F$
$\displaystyle\vec F(\vec R)=-\frac{1}{n-2}\vec\nabla\frac{1}{R^{n-2}}=\frac{\vec \eta}{R^{n-1}}\tag*{}$
Let’s consider the flow of the vector $\vec F(\vec R)$ through some closed hyper-surface surrounding the source (the origin):
$\displaystyle J_n=\int(\vec F(\vec R),d\vec S)=-\frac{1}{n-2}\int(\vec\nabla\frac{1}{R^{n-2}},d\vec S)\tag*{}$
According to Gauss theorem,
$\displaystyle J_n=-\frac{1}{n-2}\int\Delta\frac{1}{R^{n-2}}\,dV\tag*{}$ - the integral over the volume inside the surface ($\Delta$ denotes Laplacian).

But $\frac{1}{R^{n-2}}$ is the fundamental solution of the Laplace equation in $n$ dimensions (for example, look here [computations problem with reverse Fourier transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099027/computations-problem-with-reverse-fourier-transform/4099754#4099754)).
$\displaystyle \Delta\frac{1}{R^{n-2}}=-\frac{2(n-2)\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\big(n/2\big)}\delta^n (\vec R)\tag*{}$
Integrating delta function
$\displaystyle J_n=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\big(n/2\big)}\tag*{}$

We see that the total flow through any closed hyper-surface is constant (does not depend on $R$).
Therefore, we can choose as a surface the hypercube surrounding the origin, with an edge length equal to 2. There are $2n$ equal faces, and the flow through one face of the cube is$ \int_{\text{one face}}(\vec F(\vec R),d\vec S)=\int_{\text{one face}}\frac{(\vec n, d\vec S)}{R^{n-1}}=\int_{\text{one face}}\frac{dS}{R^n}$. (Drawing a picture helps a lot).
The total volume of one $(n-1)$-dimensional face (with the edge length equal to 2) is $|[-1;1]|^{n-1}=2^{n-1}$, but we want to find only a portion of the flow - through the volume $|[0;1]|^{n-1}$.
Therefore, the desired integral $I(n)$ is the portion of total flow through the closed surface: $I(n)=\frac{1}{2n} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}J_n$ (the total flow goes through $2n$ faces, and our integral is equal to the flow through $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$ part of one face).
Taking all together
$\displaystyle I(n)=\int_{[0,1]^{n-1}}\frac{1}{(1+{x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+…+{x_{n-1}}^2)^{n/2}}dx_1 … dx_{n-1}\tag*{}$

$\displaystyle=\frac{1}{2n\,2^{n-1}}\,\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\big(n/2\big)}=\frac{(\sqrt\pi)^n}{2^n\Gamma\Big(\frac{n}{2}+1\Big)}\tag*{}$
For $n=3$ and $n=4$ we get
$\displaystyle I(3)=\int_{[0,1]^2}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}dx\,dy=\frac{\pi}{6}\tag*{}$
$\displaystyle I(4)=\int_{[0,1]^3}\frac{1}{(1+x^2+y^2+z^2)^2}dx\,dy\,dz=\frac{\pi^2}{32}\tag*{}$

Answer (score 1):

Start from $\int_0^\infty \lambda^{(n+1)\over 2} e^{-\lambda x}d\lambda= x^{-{(n+3)\over 2}} \int_0^\infty u^{(n+3)\over 2}e^{-u}du$

Then replace $e^{-\lambda x}$ with $e^{-\lambda (1+\sum x^2_k)}$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I'm trying to compute my integral by using the formula that you've presented.

Comment: I'm afraid it won't work - there is no rotational symmetry (the bound us cube, not a sphere)

Comment: @Svyatoslav so what, you have $e^{-\sum x_k^2}=\prod e^{-x_k^2}$ and the integrals decouple

Comment: @user619894 this is correct - you get the factorisation on the first stage. But does help to get the closed form for the initial integral? I'm not sure ...

Comment: @Svyatoslav, perhaps. At least it becomes a 1d integral with simple limits. I got an expression with $erf()^n$. There is also the fact that the power and the dimension are related to exploit.

Comment: @user619894 I've got the following result...
$$  {\pi ^ {n/2}\over 2^n \Gamma((n+3)/2)} \int_{0}^{\infty} z^2 e^{-z^2} [\text{erf} (z)]^n dz $$

Comment: Do you have an idea of how to calculate the integral containing ${erf^n}$?

Comment: Isnt there a $z^{n}$?

Comment: @Seouldddd, I don't know how to integrate general $erf()^n$, maybe Wolfram, but  $exp^{-z^2}erf(z)^n\sim f' f^n$ seems to suggest integration by parts or change of variable to $f$.